# Conectar MySQL externo em app para realizar autenticação

Tags: android

Olá, preciso de ajuda para fazer um app para acesso a um sistema de controle de ambientes. Preciso realizar a autenticação do usuário, a partir de uma base de dados já existente, e, ao realizar essa autenticação (não precisando usar um web service, pois será para uso local apenas), é necessário mostrar ao usuário as portas que ele possui acesso, e então permitir realizar a abertura da mesma pelo app ao clicar em um botão. Obrigado.

Comment: e qual sua dúvida brother?

Comment: Fiz uma resposta para sua pergunta, mas aqui você deve colocar o problema que está tendo ao fazer o seu código e não pedir um código pronto.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode realizar o acesso ao banco de dados da maneira que deseja, mas isso não é recomendado atualmente, já que é muito mais complexo, prejudica a performance e deixa sua base vulnerável. 
Não é porque sua aplicação não roda na internet que você não pode usar um webservice para se responsabilizar pelas consultas SQL.

Caso, ainda assim, você queira fazer isso, basta importar a biblioteca de conexão do MySQL para Java no seu projeto e realizar da mesma maneira as funções do banco.

Exemplo de conexão:

```
public void conectarMySQL(String host, String porta, String banco, String usuario, String senha){
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
} catch(Exception erro){
Log.e("MYSQL","Erro: "+erro);
}

    try{
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+host+":"+porta+"/"+banco+"?connectTimeout=9000&socketTimeout=9000&autoReconnect=true&secondsBeforeRetryMaster=3",usuario,senha);
        Log.i("MYSQL", "Conectado.");
    } catch(Exception erro){
        Log.e("MYSQL","Erro: "+erro);
    }
}
```

Para usar o webservice você mesmo pode fazer o seu, criando as consultas que deseja. Eu utilizo hoje, em uma aplicação apenas de rede interna (o que parece ser seu caso) PHP + JSON, o que facilitou muito meu trabalho na interface Android.

Caso queira mais referências sobre o assunto, fica um link de sugestão: https://www.androidpro.com.br/blog/armazenamento-de-dados/usando-banco-de-dados-externo-no-android/